# Azure function not visible in function list after the function is published to portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Azure function and here found after the function is published to the portal, but it is not visible in the function list. I have attached the snap of sample code and an empty list of azure. plz, help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Adding kudu ui, here I found the only host.json in /wwwroot

[image]

Hi All

Added kudu ui, here I found the only host.json in /wwwroot

Comment: how did you publish

Comment: using visual studio 2019

Comment: Yes, this is an error.

Comment: Since the newest UI be used last week, the problem is coming.

Comment: This problem only comes when you publish function from local. If you create trigger on  portal, it will be showed successful.

Comment: The function is already be published. Why you can't trigger it is you dont give it the key.

Comment: There were no problem two weeks ago. Recently the azure function ui on azure is being updated to unify the app service, so there may be some bugs or even missing some functions than ui before. But it should be completely stable after a while.

Comment: @ Bowman Zhu thanks, I have seen the Azure Portal template online works, but I have to use Visual studio code as per project guidelines. I have added more info on KUDU here I found only host.json got deployed.

Comment: @SAM Hi, I have update my answer, you can have a look.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

From your description, it seems the deployment of your azure function is Interrupted or failed. There will be a `host.json` in wwwroot by default. If you deploy from local, it means it create function app success but didn't upload files to physical path 'wwwroot' (Azure function is based on azure app services sandbox, so if your deployment is success, all of the related files and folder will be upload to wwwroot, this is the physical path, just like the app service. ) I think you can try other ways to upload these files to physical path. For example, ftp deploy or zip deploy. This is the structure of the C# library azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#functions-class-library-project

This is the screenshot of the success deployed function:

[image]

(In bin directory, there are many compiled files, including the dll file. In Function1, there is a `function.json`. These files will be generated after building. For more information, please refer to the above doc.)

You can first build your function app on local and then upload the compiled files to azure.

These are the tutorials of how to use ftp and the zip deploy to upload files: (Just choose one of them is ok. By the way, when you use the VS 2019 to publish function app, it is essentially a zip deployment.)

FTP deploy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp

Zip deploy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

**Original Answer:**

This is an error of portal ui.

It seems that the new version of ui has not been done. But your function should have been deployed to azure.

If you go to kudu, you will find the files has be upload to wwwroot.

You should follow these steps:

[image]

And then copy the host key in this place:

[image]

(Both of them can be used.) Copy one of them to the end of your request url.

The request url in your function app should be like this:

```
yourfunctionappname.azurewebsites.net/api/yourtriggername?code=yourkey
```

And then you can get response.

[image]

You can try again at your time, the problem maybe be fixed.(Whether you can see it in ui, you can trigger this trigger, but you need to give a key to pass the verification. The new version of the function ui still has a lot of updates, and even lacks some basic functions. It is trying to unify towards app service, and it should be stable after a while.)

Comment: Hi Dude, thanks, Added kudu UI line in the post, here I found the only host.json in /wwwroot. doesn it mean that Visual Studio PUBLISH has not deployed and copied my code to WWW folder?

Comment: @SAM Sorry for I didn't respond immediately. I was doing something else. Wait a minute, I will update my answer.

Comment: Amazing Thanks for providing useful insight on kudu file structure, it is surely a problem with VS 2019. this guy is not publishing the function. Hence I tried with VS Code on different machin and it got published successfully with all file visible in KUDU and also now I can see my Sample Azure function... Thanks :)

Comment: @SAM Congratulations! :)

Comment: One last help and idea how can solve Visual studio publish because I build and finally solution with VS 2019. Here I found that my VS 2019->VIEW->OTHER WINDOWS->web publish Activity is not showing any data or information.

Comment: @SAM The deploy method that VS2019 using is zip deploy. It will pack builded files and upload to azure. I am not sure what is the root problem why your VS2019 can not publish function, But if you meet similar problem next time, you can use zip deploy directly.