# Azure Function is deployed and does work but Function Monitor doesn't display the invocation data

Tags: c#, azure, function, logging, azure-functions

I have an IoTHub Trigger Function which is sending data to an EventHub but ends up in a CosmosDB Collection.

My function was already deployed for some time but I decided to add another feature and deploy it again. The function is still working because I see new data getting inserted in the CosmosDB collection but the Function Monitor doesn't display the invocation traces. When I go to the Logs tab, it either doesn't log or I get the following error message :

"*Unable to fetch the host status of your function app. To use log streaming, please make sure your function host is running.*"

I checked my application settings and I do have the correct App Insights instrumentation key and connection string as shown in the picture below :
[image: application settings of my Function App displaying the list of keys.]

I'm not sure what the problem is here as my data still goes through the functions but I'm not able to see the logs. When running the query on App Insights I also don't get updates on the logs.

How could I troubleshoot the problem or what might help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, any update of this question?

Comment: Hi, I replied to your answer below!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a transient issue. You can create new resources and try again. Or test the next day.

By the way, if you just want to check the logs, you can do below steps(Since your function runs fine, it should work):

Go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

And click to `home\LogFiles\Application\Functions`

Comment: I already went and took a look at the logs using Kudu. I can confirm I see the logs and I also don't have any errors in the logs that might indicate that something went wrong. I will deploy the function on a new resource and update.

Comment: Update : I created a new Function App resource and published my function using it. The Invocation traces in the "Manage" blade looked like it was working properly but I checked again yesterday and today and I have the same problem again ; The function works (it processes the data) but logging doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Look at what is deployed in Azure using Kudu - this is an interface that shows what's really deployed and running under the covers :)

In Kudu you should be able to see your deployed functions as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#functions-class-library-project). (There are links on the left hand side to how it looks if you have developed in some other supported language)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805855/azure-function-not-visible-in-function-list-after-the-function-is-published-to-p) is talking about a problem similar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Kudu, I've already checked the logs prior to writing the post and I see the logs, the deployment doesn't seem to have failed but I still can't see them from the Function Monitor. I've also read the question you've sent and the next step I'll try is to re-publish the function on a new resource